# How to make a scatter plot not show all values instead of the top values only?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a scatter plot with a timestamp (aggregated by minute) for the X axis and a numerical measure for the Y axis.
The plot that I get shows only some of the values, with the text below the visual name saying "showing top 50 in [X] and top 43 in [Y]".

How do I make the scatter plot show all values?